# Getting bits from a packed word

Tags: vb.net, bitwise-operators

I have a 16 bit word that could be anywhere from 1 to 16 data values. They are decoded by knowing the MSB and lsb of the 16 bit word and grabbing those bits.

I'm using VB and I just don't know how to do this.

Example
I have a word that is
    &HA6F2
    1010 0100 1111 0010

I know my data is LSB 3 to MSB 9. Bit ordering is left to right
So the data is 010011

How do I get this in VB code? I want to work in bytes because after I get the packed bits then I have to do type casts on it (signed_fixed, integer, 2's complement, etc)

Thanks

Comment: &HA6F2 => 1010 0110 1111 0010 !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mask` (**bitwise** AND, see `And` keyword). And also probably **bitwise-right-shift** (see `>>` operator)

Conceptually:

```
1010 0100 1111 0010 '= the data
0001 1111 1100 0000 '= 1FC0 the mask
-------------------- And
0000 0100 1100 0000 '= 04C0
-------------------- >> 6
0000 0000 0001 0011 '= 0013 now your value is in the right most
```

In the code

```
Dim newData As Integer = (rawData And &H1FC0) >> 6
```